# How to overwrite stdout using echo?

Tags: text-processing, stdout, echo

We know  to overwrite `bar.txt`, we can use this:

```
echo "foo" > bar.txt
```

but how can we overwrite to the standard output? I tried this command:

```
echo "foo" >
```

but it failed. I want this because I want to print something like this:

```
Hello  

world

I'm 

HERE
```

one word at a time and I want to delete the previous word (one word at a time on standard output).

Comment: Your question is not clear. `>` operator won't append to the file actually it overwrites the file.And if you just say `echo "foo"` or `echo "foo" >&1` it prints on `stdout`.

Comment: I want to delete the word which printed on stdout then add another word

Comment: Can you add the source of the output, how do you plan to get the sources?

Comment: I'm under the impression you're confusing _stdout_ (the default destination programs write their output to), with _terminal_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo` always outputs to its stdout<sup>1</sup>. `echo foo` always does a `write(1, "foo\n")`.

When you do `echo foo > file`, the shell changes the stdout for the `echo` command to a new `file` file. `echo foo` then still does a `write(1, "foo\n")` but this time its stdout (its file descriptor 1) points to `file`, not to the stdout it inherits from the shell.

If you want to write to stdout without that stdout being *redirected*, just write:

```
echo foo
```

---

If you want the resource pointed to by stdout to be reopen (and truncated) before each `echo`, then that's trickier.

On Linux (and Linux only), you can do:

```
echo foo > /dev/fd/1
echo bar > /dev/fd/1
# now the file stdout points to (if it's a regular file) contains "bar"
```

On Linux, `/dev/fd/1` is a symlink to the file that is open on stdout. So opening it again with `>` will truncate it (on other Unices, `> /dev/fd/n` is like `dup2(n,1)` so it won't truncate the file). That won't work if stdout goes to a socket though.

Otherwise, you can call `ftruncate()` on stdout (fd 1) to truncate it:

```
perl -e 'truncate STDOUT,0'
echo foo
perl -e 'truncate STDOUT,0'
echo bar
```

---

If instead, you want those words, *when stdout is a terminal* to overwrite each other on the screen, you can use terminal control characters to affect the cursor positioning.

```
 printf %s FOO
 printf '\r%s' BAR
```

will have BAR overwrite FOO because `\r` is the control characters that instructs the terminal to move the cursor to the beginning of the line.

If you do:

```
printf %s FOOBAR
printf '\r%s' BAZ
```

however, you'll see `BAZBAR` on the screen. You may want to use another control sequence to clear the line. While `\r` as meaning carriage return is universal, the control sequence to clear the screen varies from one terminal to the next. Best is to query the terminfo database with `tput` to find it out:

```
clr_eol=$(tput el)
printf %s FOOBAR
printf '\r%s%s' "$clr_eol" BAZ
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> if using the Korn or Z shell, another outputting command that supports writing to other file descriptors is `print`: `print -u2 FOO` for instance writes `FOO` to `print`'s stderr. With `echo` and in Bourne-like shells, you can do `echo >&2 FOO` to achieve the same result. `echo` is still writing to its stdout, but its stdout has been made a duplicate of the shell's stderr using the `>&2` shell redirection operator</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can say,

$ `clear && printf "before" && sleep 1 && clear && printf "after\n"`

For your Hello world,

$ `clear && printf "Hello" && sleep 1 && clear && printf "World" && sleep 1 && clear && printf "I'm" && sleep 1 && clear && printf "Here\n"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're printing to a terminal anyway, you maybe just want to omit the newline (`-n`) and have an explicit carriage return instead:

```
echo -en 'hello, dear\r'; sleep 5; echo -en 'world\r'; echo
```

(Note that you'll want to space-pad your strings to overwrite them completely.)

Comment: Note that not all `echo` implementations support `-e` or `-n`. Actually, Unix-conformant ones don't and you have to write `echo '\b\b\b\bworld\c'` there. See [Why is printf better than echo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565) for details.

Answer (score 0):

`>` actually *redirects* stdout to a file.  What you try to do, is in other words to redirect stdout to stdout itself - which doesn't make much sence.  You got stdout already - `>` just tells the shell to put the output into a file instead of to the screen.

What you can do, is to redirect the output to virtual-terminal or pseudo-terminal you have access to (eg. command > /dev/pts/2 ), that way you can send the output from a command to another terminal then the one it's running in.

You can also create a named-pipe (fifo), whcih appears as a file.  One command can write (its stdout) to this file, while another command can read (to its stdin) from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `echo` instead of Thushi's solution with `printf`, have a look at the `-e` option of the `echo` command. This allows you to use certain escape sequences, including `\b` for backspace. Together with the `-n` option which supresses newlines you can do this:

```
 echo -n "Hello" && sleep 10 && echo -n -e "\b\b\b\b\bworld"
```

Comment: Note that not all `echo` implementations support `-e` or `-n`. Actually, Unix-conformant ones don't and you have to write `echo '\b\b\b\bworld\c'` there. See [Why is printf better than echo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565) for details.